# How to check if my Sandisk flash drive is genuine?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I bought a USB 3.0 SanDisk 32GB Flash Drive from **Aliexpress**.
How can I check if it's genuine and not a fake one?

https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005001664581327.html

Comment: Helps to notice the 4000+ reviews (all above 4 star) and read some of them.  AliExpress will allow the sale of fake stuff but I don't believe that they facilitate fake reviews.

Answer (score 1):

IMO best option is to look behind info that is easily faked (like the printing on the casing). Goal of the faker is to make (quick) money and often one way to do this is by keeping production costs down. Second way to quick money is pretend you're an A brand and thirdly lie about things like capacity: claim more than there's actually in there, higher capacity = higher price.

- Saving on production costs *may* result in visually detectable anomalies, sloppy printing for example. Problem is this is easy to tell when you can compare against a genuine drive but harder when you have nothing to compare against.
- You can pretend being an A-brand by just appearances, using logos, product descriptions etc.. In reality 3rg grade recycled hardware is being used.
- Capacity can be easily faked using so called mass-production tools, that float around in abundance over the the internet, at firmware level:

[image]

It's relatively easy to have a USB flash drive with say 8GB NAND installed report as a 64GB or 128 GB drive. You can even use such a drive to a degree until you start saving files at LBA addresses > 8 GB, but even then you will not be alarmed until you actually try to open these files!

### Detecting a fake Sandisk USB flash drive

**Visual inspection**

Carefully examine the looks of the USB flash drive. Even if you can not compare to a genuine Sandisk USB flash drive you might be able to spot a fake. In general Sandisk's are nicely finished products, looks for signs of sloppiness.

**Determine the hardware used**

Most (all?) Sandisk USB flash drives use Sandisk controller. Fakes often use a different brand controller (Alcor, Silicon), whatever they could get their hands on.

[image]

A tool like [Flash Drive Information Extractor](https://www.antspec.com/usbflashinfo/index.php) can tell the controller even if Vendor ID is faked at firmware level:

[image]

Faking the vendor ID is probably enough for most tools to ID the USB Flash Drive as a 'Sandisk' and so most tools can not be relied upon to detect the fake.

An alternative tool to determine this information is 'ChipGenius' but many copies you can find on the internet are suspicious according to many virus scanners. IOW it's risky to rely on this tool and I'd avoid it.

**Determine capacity**

Probably the most reliable tool to detect real capacity is [H2testw](https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/H2testw.shtml):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've googled "sandisk genuine" and the first result was ["Verifying if a SanDisk product is authentic"](https://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1953/%7E/verifying-if-a-sandisk-product-is-authentic) in SanDisk's Knowledge Base.

> **How do I check if I have purchased an authentic SanDisk product?**
>
> The best way to ensure you are purchasing an authentic SanDisk product
> is to buy from an authorized SanDisk reseller.
>
> View our [distributor/reseller](http://www.sandisk.com/about-sandisk/find-a-retailer) list to locate an authorized SanDisk
> reseller in your area.
>
> If you are concern about the authenticity of your SanDisk product, you
> may contact [SanDisk's tech support](http://www.sandisk.com/about-sandisk/contact-us/) and select the appropriate tech
> support option for your product.

You've already purchased the product from an unknown source, so you should [contact their support](http://www.sandisk.com/about-sandisk/contact-us/).